# UICollectionView not displayed to view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have been stuck on this problem for nearly a week now. I have even reverted my code and wrote the same code as some tutorials but I cannot seem to get my `UICollectionView` to be displayed to the view for the life of me.  I have a lot of other code going on in my view controllers so I am going to display the code that pertains to the `UICollectionView`. This is what I have so far:

**view controller:**

```
class UARTModuleViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMenuBar()
    }

    let menuBar: MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb
    }()

    private func setupMenuBar() {
        view.addSubview(menuBar)
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":menuBar])
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0(100)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":menuBar])
        view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
        view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
    }
}
```

**MenuBar.swift:**

```
class MenuBar : UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")

        //took out constraints here just to make the warning mentioned below easier to follow.
    }
```

I do have my protocols implemented but I didn't add them just to save the amount of code I'm posting. I do get this warning after the `UARTModuleViewController` loads :

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

I've tried reasoning through it and can't seem to come to a solution. I do have a cell class as well but thought it was not necessary to include since I can't get the `UICollectionView` to be displayed. The only other thing that I may add is that I have a `UIImageView` in the middle of the view that I added in story board and put constraints on like so: [image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help or advice that can be given.

Comment: How should the Menu bar be displayed?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio right now I'm just trying to get it to display. eventually it will sit under the `UIImageView` at the bottom of the screen. It will take up width of the screen and then the height will be almost to the bottom of the `UIImageView`.

Comment: You want the collection view to have same size of the parent view?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio only the width will be the same width as the parent view. the height will be smaller. I don't have set values yet as I'm just trying to display it. It will probably be ~1/5 of the parent view height I'm guessing.

Comment: I mean, the collection view will be cover entire MenuBar?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio yes that is correct, sorry I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments:

- First of all, every time you use constraint in code, you must set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to the view you want to add constraint.
- You're not telling the collection view to fill entire `MenuBar` space.
- Constraints applied to `MenuBar` in `setupMenuBar` are not enaugh to determine the size and position of the view.

These are changes you should apply to tell the `MenuBar` to fill width, be 60 pt height and to position on bottom of the screen:

```
private func setupMenuBar() {
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    menuBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // this will make your constraint working
    menuBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true // every constraint must be enabled.
    menuBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
}
```

To tell the collection view to fill entire `MenuBar` view do this in `MenuBar` `init(frame:)` method:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    //took out constraints here just to make the warning mentioned below easier to follow.
}
```

As you can see in my code, I usually use "anchor" methods to apply constraint because are easier than visual format.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Earlier I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` but I didn't realize that the constraints weren't enough to determine size/position of the view. This worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation as well!